# Tengo este codigo y me suelta esto Line 99: TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given ¿alguien tiene idea?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Stage(Scene):
    def __init__(self, location, scale, tilt, domain = [0, CANVAS['WIDTH']]):   
        Scene.__init__(self, location, scale, tilt, domain)
        
class Player(Character, Image):
    def __init__(self, image, location, scale, tilt = 0.0, frames = 1, domain = [0, CANVAS['WIDTH']]):
        Character.__init__(self, location, scale, tilt, domain)
        Image.__init__(self, image, frames)
        self.speed = [0.0, 0.0]
        self.acc = [0.0, 0.0]
        self.ground = 550
        
    def phisics(self, vector):
        self.acc = vector
        if self.location[1] + self.speed[1] + self.acc[1] < self.ground:
           self.speed[1] += self.acc[1]
        else:
            self.speed[1] = 0.0
        self.location[1] += self.speed[1]
```

Comment: Agrega el código donde se crea un objeto de clase `Stage`. Parece que se le están pasando más parámetros de los que espera.

Comment: Cuál es la linea 99?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.